# Position and prominence of 'Acknowledgements' in a publication

Tags: writing, acknowledgement

What is the appropiate position for the 'Acknowledgements' in a paper? Are there policies by (mathematical) journals where to put them?

Furthermore, is it common to make acknowledgements a \paragraph (in Latex), rather than a \subsection or a final \section?

Comment: As with every other question of the form "Where should I put X in my paper?", the answer is **"In the same place as the papers you cite."**

Comment: @JeffE ...or in the place that the journal specifies in their "Instructions for Authors" document or formatting template.

Comment: some journals explicitly mention where you should put Acknowledgements. If it is not mentioned, then I believe the default place for them is right after the conclusion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I generally make acknowledgements their own `\section` and place it at the end of the paper's body, before the references or any appendices.

But I really don't think it matters.  The referee is not going to care, and it won't affect the acceptance or rejection of the paper.  If the journal has a preference, you will hear about it from the copy editor when the time comes to correct the proofs.

You might as well check the Instructions for Authors to see if it addresses this, but otherwise, just pick something reasonable and don't worry about it.

Answer (score 7):

Acknowledgements generally go a separate section after the conclusion.  [You can see the Elsevier advice on acknowledgements sections here](http://www.elsevier.com/journals/research-policy/0048-7333/guide-for-authors#48000). If you have a specific conference or journal you are submitting to, and want to know what other authors have done, browse some of the previous volumes' papers or proceedings.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure the position may differ slightly beween journals but commonly it is placed after the conclusions and before the reference list. In some cases the Acknowledgement may be a note at the end of the paper. The journal would hopefully clearly indicate where they want such information in the manuscript. Please refeer to the "Instructions for Authors" (equiv) for any journal you are considering. If you are unsure, ask the editor.

As for the (La)TeX question, the formatting will obviosuly differ depening on the instructions for the specific journal you are targeting. Many journals also have specific (La)TeX classes for manuscripts which may provide further insights into hpow the journal wants the paper structured.